# "Painter not active" al usar QPainter dentro de paintEvent

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Estaba realizando una practica de dibujo con polygonos en pyqt5 pero me lanza el siguiente error:

```
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
```

Este es el codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPolygon,QPainter,QPen,QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint,Qt
from PyQt5 import uic

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


    def paintEvent(self,event):

        painter = QPainter()
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black,5,Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green,Qt.SolidPattern))

        points = [
            QPoint(10,10),
            QPoint(10,100),
            QPoint(100,10),
            QPoint(100,100)
        ]
        poly = QPolygon(points)
        painter.drawPolygon(poly)


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

No muestra ningun tipo de dibujo, solo esta la ventana en blanco y cada que cambia el tamaño de la ventana se muestra el error otra vez.

Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPainter sirve para pintar sobre un QPaintDevice como en este caso es el QMainWindow, pero tu no le has indicado donde pintar, y ante ello Qt te avisa de tu error. La solucion es pasarle a la ventana en el constructor:

```py
# ...
def paintEvent(self,event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    # ...
```

O usar el método begin():

```py
# ...
def paintEvent(self,event):
    painter = QPainter()
    painter.begin(self)
    # ...
```